# Resizing images in PDF using iText: incompatible color conversion

Tags: java, colors, compression, itext

I'm trying to reduce the filesize of a few PDF's in Java. I've found a few techniques to do this. But resizing images seems most effective.
I followed [this piece of code](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/print.php?article_id=327) which uses iText.

It works great on a few PDF's (reduction from 4.5MB to 800KB!) but some stayed unaffected.

I altered the code a bit as follows, so it would accept more Stream objects (and hopefully compress more):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(original.getPath());
int size = reader.getXrefSize();
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    PdfObject object = reader.getPdfObject(i);
    if (object == null || !object.isStream())
        continue;
    PRStream stream = (PRStream)object;
        PdfImageObject image = new PdfImageObject(stream);
        try{
        BufferedImage bi = image.getBufferedImage();
        //more stuff here
```

And it did! Some PDF's actually got compressed a lot more. However, I got a strange exception at some that didn't change at all:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Incompatible color conversion
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkColorConversion(JPEGImageReader.java:927)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1028)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:984)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1438)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1342)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject.getBufferedImage(PdfImageObject.java:302)
    at com.example.compression.App.main(App.java:56)
```

(App.java:56 being the line that says `image.getBufferedImage();`)

Some research discovered, the Stream it was trying to open was a **CMYK** JPG.

I'm wondering why these wouldn't open, and how I can resize these images anyway.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BufferedImage doesn't deal with CMYK nativally (and I'm not sure if Java does in other native components, anyway).

In the fields listed in [Java 6 docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), there's no cmyk color model....

You can take a look at [this site](http://carback.us/rick/blog/?p=58), someone tells you how to deal with BufferedImage and CMYK colorspace.

Good luck!